# global 2D array values changing between modules

Tags: arrays, c, extern

I have a 2D extern array "the_board[17][25]". I am fairly new to C and believe I have some linking issue. in my board.c file I initialized the board, giving every cell a value. when calling the board in my other functions, the values change, even though I have made no edits to the array since initializing it.

header file to declared array:

```
#define BOARD_SIZE_X 25
#define BOARD_SIZE_Y 17
extern int the_board[BOARD_SIZE_Y][BOARD_SIZE_X];
#define DA 0            /* disallowed */
#define RE 1            /* red */
#define GR 2            /* green */
#define EM 7            /* empty */
```

board.c file containing initialization:

```
#include "my_header.h"
int the_board[BOARD_SIZE_Y][BOARD_SIZE_X] = {
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7},
    {0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0},
    {0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0},
    {0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0},
    {7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
};
```

Sorry for the large block of code it has to be manually defined. This is where the problem I run into. When calling the_board[][], the values become screwed up. For an example this is what happens when I print the_board[BOARD_SIZE_Y][BOARD_SIZE_X] in main.c:

img of array: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLQqT.png

```
#include "my_header.h"
int main() {
int i, j;
int the_board[BOARD_SIZE_Y][BOARD_SIZE_X];

    for (i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE_Y; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE_X; j++) {
            printf(" %d ", the_board[i][j]);
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include my_header.h`  should be `#include "my_header.h"`

Comment: You could pass a pointer to the board explicitly to all functions that use it. It's less elegant, but at least you always know what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

You have one initialised global `the_board`, defined in board.c.
You have one non-initialised local `the_board` defined inside `main()`.
That second one hides the first one.
Delete the line which defines it, i.e.

```
int the_board[BOARD_SIZE_Y][BOARD_SIZE_X];
```

Comment: I originally thought that to be a problem as well but, then my program does not compile. I am given the error : undefined reference to  `the_board'

Comment: That error indicates a problem with building correctly. Please describe that in a separate question on how to build/link those two code files. Show the code which only defines in one code file and give details on how exactly you build.

Comment: @Jake: Are you specifying both source files on the command-line when compiling your program? It sounds to me that you are only compiling the source file containing `main` and not `board.c`.

Comment: Other way around is to add `extern` to the local variable to make it a declaration of the global `the_board`

Comment: I believe so. I am using Clion to compile and it should do it automatically as long as all the .c files are in the same project folder. Just to be sure I moved the function used in board.c into main.c and the same error occured @AndreasWenzel

Comment: @tstanisl I thought extern is reserved only for defining the variable?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "defined". I suspect you mix up "defined" and "declared". I use "declaring" for "telling the compiler that it exists" and I use "defining" for "making the variable exist". Defining should only be done once - and not in a header. Declaring is for headers and for being done in all code which refers to the variable.

Comment: @Jake: My only explanation is that the code you are showing us is not your actual code. The fact that you had initially posted `#include my_header.h` instead of `#include <my_header.h>`, until somebody pointed out the mistake, corroborates my suspicion. Make sure that the identifier `the_board` is spelled correctly in all files.